# Facebook like button: Hard to click - small hotspot

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

For some reason the Facebook Like button on my webpage has only a small hotspot, I'm only able to click in the area just under where it says 'like' rather than the whole Like button.

http://www.melbournedodgeball.com.au/team/3

If I go to a page for a team that does not exist, the problem is not there:

http://www.melbournedodgeball.com.au/team/300

Any ideas why this could be the case?

Answer (score 2):

Upon inspection with chrome inspector, it seems your

```
<h2> Ya Mum!</h2>
```

element is somehow blocking part of the like button where it is clickable. if you could somehow shrink the width or get it to stop flowing over the like button, the problem will be solved.

Edit: Tried changing font size for h2 and it also made the whole "like" button clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its the position:absolute on the iframe, try just using float and you should be right.

Comment: hmm it works okay on all the other pages using the same styles though, e.g: http://www.melbournedodgeball.com.au/game/14
is there anything else i could do to fix it?